# Cole-Hopf transform of a PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Consider the modified traffic wave equation $$\rho_{t}+(1-2\rho)\rho_{x}=\rho_{xx}$$ subject to initial condition $\rho_{(x,0)}=f(x)$.

(a),Show that there exists a function $\psi$ such that $$\psi_{x}=\rho,\psi_{t}=-\rho+\rho^2+\rho_{x}.$$

(b), Use Cole-Hopf transform to reduce the nonlinear PDE to a linear PDE.

Note: For (a) I have converted the equation to the form $$\rho_{t}-(-\rho+\rho^2+\rho_{x})_{x}=0$$, but what guarentees the existence of $\psi$?

For (b) I think it requires a generalised Hopf transform (not the one for solving the standard Burgers' equation),and I suspect the linear equation will be a heat equation.

Answer (score 2):

> what guarantees the existence of $\psi$?

A function $\psi:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ with prescribed derivatives $\psi_x=u$ and $\psi_t=v$ exists if and only if $u_t=v_x$. (Recall *conservative vector field*, *potential function*). In your case the conservative condition is $\rho_t = (-\rho+\rho^2+\rho_x)_x$, which is equivalent to the given PDE.

Answer (score 1):

For (b),

Let $u=1-2\rho$ ,

Then $\rho=\dfrac{1-u}{2}$

$\rho_t=-\dfrac{u_t}{2}$

$\rho_x=-\dfrac{u_x}{2}$

$\rho_{xx}=-\dfrac{u_{xx}}{2}$

$\therefore-\dfrac{u_t}{2}-u\dfrac{u_x}{2}=-\dfrac{u_{xx}}{2}$

$u_t+uu_x=u_{xx}$ , which reduces to the standard Burgers' equation